# MS Access prevent simultaneous check out of same kit

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a database in MS Access 2010 for a lending library (and realize that there's a template in 2013 but I've already invested time into my own).  My big problem is preventing two users from borrowing the same kit simultaneously.  Here are the relevant tables:

KIT (**KIT_ID**, ITEM_ISBN)

LOAN (USER_ID, **KIT_ID**, **CHECK_OUT_DATE**, CHECK_IN_DATE, STATUS)

USER (**USER_ID**, USER_LNAME, USER_FNAME, JOB_CODE)

My users will return kits to the library and shelve them without checking them in so this really is a problem - I need the system to control that behavior.  The issue is exacerbated when a kit is finally checked in but doesn't check it in to all the outstanding check outs.  There are multiple tuples in the LOAN table of the same kit being checked out without a check in date.  If a kit can only be checked out to one user at a time then that would solve my problems.  There would then only be one record of a kit with a status of "Not Available" (that would not have a value in the CHECK_IN_DATE field).

Is there some validation rule I'm missing at the LOAN table, do I have the primary keys set incorrectly, am I indexing the wrong fields?

Maybe my form is the problem.  The record source is the LOAN table and it is set for data entry.  The available fields in the form are USER_ID, KIT_ID and CHECK_OUT_DATE.

If you've guessed that I'm a bit of a novice who can create macros but doesn't know enough code to generate my own (just copy it) then you're correct.  I would appreciate your help, though, and thank you in advance!

Comment: simple: when checking out, check if there's any loan records for that kit where there ISN'T a checkin date. that means it's out. it doesn't make sense to allow the loan of an item that's "out" from the system's point of view. prevent those bad "no checkin" records from being created in the first place, rather than trying to compensate for their existence.

Comment: Hi, Marc!  I thought of creating an read-only subform that would enable users to view the status of a kit.  I want the system to still prevent them from trying to check out an already unavailable kit.  Ummm, I don't trust my users to either check the availability of a kit or to not attempt to check something out anyway.  I really need to prevent them from creating a new record in the LOAN table for a kit that has not been checked in.

Comment: so you need some code in `checkout()` that checks if the kit can even be borrowed in the first place. this isn't a thing you leave up to the users. YOUR system has to enforce the rules, not leave it up to the users to know every single little detail.

Comment: Yup, that's what I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: in the combo where they select the kit, you use the SQL recordsource and exclude kits where there is no check in date

Comment: Well, I ended up doing some screwy things but that seem to work: call CHECK_OUT form from BORROW_KIT form.  On click of saving CHECK_OUT form it also closes and opens BORROW_KIT form, from which there is an "Available" or "Not Available" status that makes available the CHECK_OUT or CHECK_IN forms.  I borrowed this from looking at the 2013 template.  Still not sure exactly what code to put in, though, but this may be a temporary solution to help manage the situation.